# How to check null value from REDIS MGET via Jedis client in java

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have some keys in redis. I can do a MGET and fetch the values. But when the key is not present I get a **(nil)** from redis. But how to check that in java ? I am checking for **null** but it is not working.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET key1 key2 key3 key4
1) "Hello"
2) "World"
3) "Hi"
4) "Hi-World"
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET key1 key2 key3 key5 key4
1) "Hello"
2) "World"
3) "Hi"
4) (nil)
5) "Hi-World"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

In my java class actually I am mapping the key-list and value-list from **MGET** in a hash map. And on the value list I am doing some operations. There I need to put a null check. But simple java `null` is not working.

Comment: Which Jedis version are you using? Please add shortest reproducible Java code that you think is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call [exists](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/redis.clients.jedis.Jedis/exists) to check if a key exists in Redis. To check with java, first, create a client and call the appropriate method.

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port);
List<String> values = jedis.mget(keys); //get all values for the given keys
values.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null)); //remove all null values
if(jedis.exists(key)) { //check if a particular key exists or not
     System.out.println(key + " exists");
}
```

Comment: This is to check a particular key. Again in that case I need to loop through the entire List. I am using mget and getting the list and returning the list. In somewhere else I am looping through the list and checking if its null. How to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can remove all null values before returning the values

Comment: This will remove if the value is exactly null. But it is returning `(nil)` and  and not a `null` . There is my problem. How do I do a null check on that. Please see the output from REDIS in my question.

Comment: Actually I am mapping the key-list and value-list in a hash map. And on the value list I am doing some operations. There I need to put a null check.

Comment: I've just run some codes again on my PC and it returns `null` in java instead of `nil` if I try to get some values that don't exist in Redis via `mget`. It shows nil in the console though.

Comment: You can always loop through the keys and check if it exists in the redis and then gets it and add it to the HashMap as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have object as a map then you can access it like this**

```
System.out.println(redissonClient.getMap("object").get("key")==null);
```

Comment: I am not using redisson